# How do I find SFDX CLI default installation folder on Mac?

Tags: salesforcedx, illuminatedcloud, mac-os-x

I was not able to use Illuminated Cloud on Mac since it required to enter Salesforce DX executable path which I don't know.

When I installed SFDX, it never asked me for a folder to install, so I didn't understand where it was installed.

How do I find where SFDX executable is installed to paste it here?

[image]

Comment: @patlalus, are you able to solve this issue? I am getting error as  Failed to obtain the org list from the Salesforce CLI: • status = 1 • message = ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/netadmin/.sfdx'. I am not sure if its setup issue or permission issue

Comment: well, I stopped using Illuminated Cloud and using VS Code instead. As far as I remember, which sfdx command helped me to find the path. I don't remember if that helped to resolve illuminated cloud settings

Comment: Ok @patlatus. which sfdx command helped me to get the path but it didn't help with the setup issue. I also start to use the vscode.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you can run it from a terminal, you can use:

```
which sfdx
```

For me, this returns:

```
/usr/local/bin/sfdx
```

Comment: That's not the install directory, that's the location of the executable. Could you please remove this answer?

Comment: Despite the question title, the final question in the body is "How do I find where SFDX executable is installed to paste it here?" My answer is the answer to that question, and the asker accepted it as solving their problem.

Answer (score 3):

From cmd.exe

`where sfdx`

From PowerShell

`get-command sfdx`

Any UNIX shell

`which sfdx`

Answer (score 2):

The folder is `/usr/local/lib/sfdx/bin/sfdx`.

To find this, one has to type command `find / -iname sfdx` in the Terminal.

[image]